# How to create Pandas DataFrame from object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing, web-scraping

I am learning to web scrape using MLB data. I would just like the team and the WAR data. I am not sure how to parse only the data that I am looking for. I do not desire the team record or the parenthesis. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My hope is to create a Pandas DataFrame with the desired output.

Data needed: 1) Team  2))WAR

Desired data format(below):

Team   WAR

ARI     1.3

ATL     1.87

BAL     2.60

BOS      .43

[image]
...

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2020-team-starting-lineups.shtml'

test = pd.read_html(url)

for t in test:
    team = t['Tm']    
    print(team)
```

I am not sure how to parse out the extra data. Thanks in advance for your time and suggestions. =)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas-series-str-extract) to get the information from the column:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2020-team-starting-lineups.shtml'

test = pd.read_html(url)

for t in test:
    team = t['Tm'].str.extract(r'^(?P<Team>[A-Z]+).*?(?P<WAR>[^\s]+)\s*oWAR')
    print(team)
```

Prints:

```
   Team    WAR
0   ARI   1.31
1   ATL   1.87
2   BAL   2.60
3   BOS   0.43
4   CHC   2.64
5   CHW   3.09
6   CIN   0.75
7   CLE  -0.81
8   COL   1.89
9   DET   1.40
10  HOU   1.64
11  KCR   0.74
12  LAA   0.58
13  LAD   4.51
14  MIA   1.34
15  MIL  -1.00
16  MIN   2.66
17  NYM   3.58
18  NYY   3.24
19  OAK   3.11
20  PHI   2.12
21  PIT  -1.89
22  SDP   2.65
23  SEA   0.67
24  SFG   1.05
25  STL   0.31
26  TBR   3.26
27  TEX   0.26
28  TOR   0.87
29  WSN   0.11
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Is that regex? I am not familiar with that style of coding but grateful nonetheless. I will try to study it and thankful for the learning experience. I will vote this answer as the best if there are no alternative that are superior. Thanks again for your time.